# Repos not working on Fedora. Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'

Tags: fedora, repository

It's my first hour using Fedora, and I wanted to install something using dnf. And the result is this:

```
[root@localhost iron]# dnf makecache 
Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'
```

I did not touch anything, this was one of my first commands (wanted to customize GNOME). Any idea how to fix it? The repo file is big, and was not changed. I'm using the Fedora downloaded today. I believe it is 26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a temporary problem with Fedora's DNS yesterday — a DNSSEC issue — right when you were having this issue. That problem is now resolved.

Comment: Does it happen often?

Comment: @alex3wielki Definitely not. Of course as a community project, we don't have any uptime guarantees, but this was a rare occurrence.

Comment: Ok. Lucky me then ;)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that :)

Comment: it just happens ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ran `dnf clean all`. Seems to work. Also I had to change my DNS to OpenDNS. My ISP doesn't like Red Hat apparently